# I want to filter files between data range pattern

Tags: awk, datefield

I tried

```
awk '$6 ~ /^2017-04-01/,/^2017-04-11/' filename
```

and another way

```
awk '$6~/^2017-07-04/, $6~/^2017-07-10/' filename
```

But it displayed all month data. what changes should done to filter range dated files.

Comment: format your question, see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help... add sample input data and expected output... see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38972736/how-to-select-lines-between-two-patterns for using flags

Comment: Can you please include some sample input data, along with the results you are getting and the results you are looking for, based on that sample? It's very hard to diagnose your problem if we don't have a problem example that can be replicated.

Answer (score 1):

you can write it this way

```
awk '"2017-04-01" <= $6  && $6 <= "2017-04-11"'  file
```

for regex you should implement the range as patterns

```
awk '$6~/^2017-04-(0[1-9]|1[01])/' file
```

however, I think the first alternative is cleaner, faster as well.

Comment: Hey Thanks all your response. awk '"2017-04-01" <= $6  && $6 <= "2017-04-11"' command given correct results as expected.